# Which method for using classes in Java?

Tags: java, class, syntax

I have seen two ways to draw from another class.

First and more simply:

```
"public class apples extends tuna{"
```

And another method which looks like:

```
tuna tunaObject = new tuna ():
tunaObject.test();
```

As far as I know these two lines do the same thing and they draw from another class. The second way just seems way harder than it has to be.

Comment: No they don't do the same thing, not even close. The scope of this question is a bit broad and likely too broad for this site. It's essentially a "please explain inheritance vs. composition to me" type question. Closing as a duplicate, but if you have further questions, please read up in your book or tutorial chapter on Java inheritance and also on composition.

Comment: So they do not do the same thing and I need to look into knowing the difference. Thanks.

Comment: The first -- `class Foo extends Bar`  uses inheritance, to give Foo Bar properties while `Bar bar = new Bar()` creates a new Bar object and assigns it to a bar variable. Again these are core Java concepts that you're not going to learn here. Again, study your texts as it's all fully explained there.

Comment: An elephant is made of (I.e. is composed of) a trunk, 4 legs, a tail etc. An elephant is a specialisation (I.e extends) mammal which extends animal